# Kotlin, Java - Call a function but postpone its execution until another function has been called

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm building a `RecyclerView` in an Android app and I inflate its items asynchronously (I inflate a `Framelayout` synchronously and right after I call the asynchronous inflation of the "real" view). The `RecyclerView` could call `onBindViewHolder` before that asynchronous inflation has finished to execute.

So the behaviour I want is the following: Function `A` gets called once. If function `B` has been executed, `A` starts to execute. But if function `B` has not been executed yet, then `A` will start its execution right after `B` finished to execute.
Things to consider: There is a callback when `B` finishes to execute and it happens on the same thread where `A` gets called. Both `A` and `B` are methods of the object `x` let's say.

Some ideas on how I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using coroutines:

```
val bHasBeenCalled = Job()
fun a() {
  scope.launch {
    bHasBeenCalled.join()
    doA()
  }
}
fun b() {
  doB()
  bHasBeenCalled.complete()
}
```